# Is it possible to cast an NSInteger to NSNumber?

Tags: objective-c, casting, nsnumber, nsinteger

Is it possible to cast a NSInteger to a NSNumber object?

I need to convert the tag of a UIImageView object to a NSNumber object because I need to pass it as an argument to a function.

Comment: It's absolutely possible to cast an NSInteger to an NSNumber*. The result will most likely lead to a crash. Of course if you have a number x, you can use @(x) to create an NSNumber object with the value x. Which will work, but is not a cast.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You cannot *cast* it because `NSInteger` is not an object, just an alias for a built-in type. You can always create a new `NSNumber` object from `NSInteger`, like this:

```
NSNumber *myNum = @(myNsIntValue);
```

or in the prior version of the compiler, use

```
NSNumber *myNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:myNsIntValue];
```

Answer (score 19):

since `Apple LLVM Compiler 4.0`, there is an easier way to create `NSNumber` object:

```
NSNumber *x = @1234; 
NSNumber *y = @(anIntegerVariable);
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the more correct answer and it will not produce unexpected error.

```
NSNumber *myNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:myNsIntValue];
```

Because the doc said:

"numberWithInteger:
Creates and returns an NSNumber object containing a given value, treating it as an NSInteger."

"numberWithInt:
Creates and returns an NSNumber object containing a given value, treating it as a signed int."